# Select head node after minimum-weight spanning tree algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I've implemented [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) to find the minimum-weight spanning tree of my graph, and it works fine.

Now I'd like to select the "best" head in the spanning tree. By "best" I mean the more *balanced* head, should I display the tree in a treeView UI for instance. I'm sure there are plenty of algorithms for that, but I don't know how to name the problem !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One criteria you can use is the average distance from node to all the other nodes. Choose the node with minimum average distance. You can also probably try average square distance etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are `splay trees` and `AVL Trees` that does what you are asking for but those are limited to a max of 2 children per node.
You could try modifying them. The problem could be `Form a tree which is as wide as possible`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "innermost" node, maximizing the min distance to a leaf.  To compute it, i think the following algorithm may work (I did not verify it):

```
S = set of all leaves of the tree
foreach node in S: mark(node)
repeat:
  # at each iteration, S is the set of all nodes at
  # a given min distance to a leave
  # initially this distance is 0, then 1, etc.
  S' = empty set
  foreach node in S:
    parent = parent(node)
    if !marked(parent): S' += parent; mark(parent)
  if S' is empty then S contains all innermost nodes, we are done
  S = S' and continue
```